# How do you assign multiple integers from print statement python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My end goal is  to get:

- 1
- 12
- 123
- 1234
- ....
- 123456789

and perform another calculation such as (1*8), (12*8), (123*8).

So far for code I have:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        print(j)
    print()

>>> 
1

1
2

1
2
3

1
2
3
4
```

How do I get them to be one long integer? The hint the textbook provides is "Consider using strings to build numbers then convert."

Comment: `int(..)` is what you need.

Comment: Actually just use the variable(s) `i`/`j` from the loop(s) and do your calculations. They would already be integers anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

I used your source code as basis. I added the `num` `string` variable. `num` is used to build the number `string` in each iteration and is reset in each outer loop iteration. To build the respective `string` we use line `num = num + str(j)` in the inner loop. `+` is used here to **concatenate** two `strings` and `str()` to convert the `integer` `j` to a `string`. After iterating over the respective numbers inside the inner loop and creating the respective `string`, at the end of each outer loop iteration we place our `print` statements. There `int()` is used to convert the created `string` to an `integer`.

```
for i in range(1,10):
    num = ''
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        num = num + str(j)
    print(int(num))
```

**Output**

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
12345678
123456789
```

You could now, for example, slightly adapt line `print(int(num))` to `print(int(num)*8)` to multiply each printed number by `8`.

This would then output:

```
8
96
984
9872
98760
987648
9876536
98765424
987654312
```

Answer (score 2):

A more efficient approach is to use math:

```
n = 0
for i in range(1, 10):
    n = n * 10 + i
    print(n)
```

This outputs:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
12345678
123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make one long integer, you first need to convert the number to string.

```
for i in range(1,10):
    tmp_code = ""
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        # convert the number to string
        tmp_code += str(j)
    print(tmp_code)
```

Then you will get:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
12345678
123456789
```